# How to configure karma and systemjs to run tests for angular ES6 transpiled by traceur into amd format ES5 modules

Tags: angularjs, gulp, karma-runner, ecmascript-6, systemjs

Ok, I have been pounding my head against the desk for far too long, it is time to ask for help.
Maybe I am way off base, or I just cannot see the trees in the forest.  Please help.

I am trying to build an application using gulp, Angular 1.3+, ES6, traceur, SystemJS, es_module_loader and http-server.

So far the app is looking good, it compiles and runs and hosts just fine from the compiled folder location, but I cannot get Karma to run a single test within my compiled project.

Here is my project structure:

```
gulpfile.js
client/
    - src
        - app/
            - bootstrap.js
            - system.config.js
            - index.html
            - modules/
                  - app.module.es6
                  - AppRouter.es6
                  - app.less
                  - common/
                       - common.module.es6
                       - masterTemplate/
                               - MasterTemplateController.es6
                               - MasterTemplateController.spec.es6
                               - masterTemplate.tpl
                               - masterTemplate.less
                  - home/
                      - home.module.es6
                      - home.less
                      - greeting/
                            - GreetingController.es6
                            - GreetingController.spec.es6
                            - greeting.less
                            - greeting.tpl
                    ...
```

using gulp and traceur I am able to transpile all the es6 code to es5 modules with amd wrappers. 
The compiled artifacts are laid out in a build folder as such:

```
_build/
   - css/
   - fonts/
   - img/
   - js/
      - lib/...
      - modules/
         - common/...
         - home/
             - greeting/
                  - GreetingController.js
             - home.module.js
         - app.module.js
         - AppRouter.js
         - mock.app.module.js
      - bootstrap.js
      - system.config.js
   - index.html
```

The compiled layout is not identical to the source layout, but it is very close:

- The vendor libs are in the `lib` folder and come from 3 different places (npm, bower and a custom download).
- The `fonts`, `css` and `img` folders are collected from several sources.
- The `_build/js` folder is nearly identical to the `client/src/app folder`, except the `index.html` file is one level up.
- The html template files (`*.tpl`) {some call these partials} are all compiled into a $templateCache module 
  saved under `_build/js/modules/common/templates/templates.module.js`

then I serve it up using http-server.  The `index.html` loads up the runtime infrastructure 
and finally the `bootstrap.js`, which uses SystemJs to bootstrap angular starting with the `/modules/`.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">

    <script src="/js/lib/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/lib/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/system.config.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view="main" class="root-view"></div>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works great.  Everything loads and present as it should.

Now I go to test it...  Because I am using SystemJs to load all dependencies (identified using `import` in each module and subsequent src file) I need to use **karma-systemjs** to help karma find and load those same files.
Here is my `karma.config.js`, which is stored at `client/src/tests/karma/karma.config.js`

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../../../../,
    urlRoot: '',
    hostname: 'localhost',
    frameworks: [ 'systemjs','mocha','chai','chai-as-promised','sinon-chai'],
    plugins: [
      'karma-mocha',
      'karma-chai',
      'karma-chai-plugins',
      'karma-systemjs',
      'karma-traceur-preprocessor',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-spec-reporter',
      'karma-junit-reporter',
      'karma-failed-reporter'
    ],
    systemjs: {
      configFile: '_build/js/system.config.js',
      files: [
        '_build/js/lib/*.js',
        '_build/js/modules/**/*.js',
        'client/src/app/**/*Spec.es6'
      ],
      config: {
        transpiler: 'traceur',
        paths: {
          'angular':           '_build/js/lib/angular.min.js',
          'angular-animate':   '_build/js/lib/angular-animate.min.js',
          'angular-messages':  '_build/js/lib/angular-messages.min.js',
          'angular-aria':      '_build/js/lib/angular-aria.min.js',
          'angular-resource':  '_build/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js',
          'angular-cookies':   '_build/js/lib/angular-cookies.min.js',
          'angular-storage':   '_build/js/lib/angular-storage.min.js',
          'angular-material':  '_build/js/lib/angular-material.min.js',
          'angular-mocks':     '_build/js/lib/angular-mocks.js',
          'angular-ui-router': '_build/js/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js',
          'statehelper':       '_build/js/lib/statehelper.min.js',
        }
      },
      testFileSuffix: '.spec.js'
    },
    preprocessors: {
      'client/src/app/**/*.spec.es6': ['traceur']  // pre-compile tests
    },
    traceurPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        modules: 'amd',
      },
    },
    client: {
      mocha: {
        reporter: 'html',
        ui: 'bdd'
      }
    },
    reporters: ['junit', 'spec', 'failed'],
    reportSlowerThan: 1000,
    junitReporter: {
      outputFile: 'reports/unit-test-results.xml',
      suite: ''
    },
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: [
       'Chrome'
    ],
    captureTimeout: 10000,
    port: 9876,
    runnerPort: 9100,
    singleRun: true,
    background: false
  });
};
```

after I build the app and run `gulp karma` I get this incredibly useful error message:

```
ERROR [karma]: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal module name "/base/client/src/app/modules/home/greeting/GreetingController.spec"
at http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js?3aac9167d6f21486de90ab673ff41c414843e2b4:2667

Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac OS X 10.10.2): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.399 secs / 0 secs)


[02:17:59] 'karma' errored after 1.81 s
[02:17:59] Error: 1
    at formatError (/Users/kpburson/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/kpburson/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/kpburson/projects/ver-client/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /Users/kpburson/projects/ver-client/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/Users/kpburson/projects/ver-client/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/Users/kpburson/projects/ver-client/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at removeAllListeners (/Users/kpburson/projects/ver-client/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:220:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/kpburson/projects/ver-client/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:231:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:199:16)
```

The `system.config.js` file is:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: '/js/', 
  paths: {
    'angular':          '/js/lib/angular.js',
    'angular-animate':  '/js/lib/angular-animate.js',
    'angular-aria':     '/js/lib/angular-aria.js',
    'angular-cookies':  '/js/lib/angular-cookies.js',
    'angular-material': '/js/lib/angular-material.js',
    'angular-messages': '/js/lib/angular-messages.js',
    'angular-mocks':    '/js/lib/angular-mocks.js',
    'angular-resource': '/js/lib/angular-resource.js',
    'angular-storage':  '/js/lib/angular-storage.js',
    'angular-ui-router':'/js/lib/angular-ui-router.js',
    'statehelper':      '/js/lib/statehelper.js'
  },
  meta: {
    'angular': {format: 'global', exports: 'angular'},
    'angular-ui-router': {format: 'global', deps: ['angular']},
    'statehelper': {format: 'global', deps: ['angular', 'angular-ui-router']}
  }
});
```

and the `bootstrap.js` file is:

```
System.import('app.module').then(
  function (a) {
    angular.element(document).ready(
      function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
      }
    );
  },
  function (a, b, c) {
    console.out('\na:', a, '\nb:', b, '\nc:', c);
  }
);
```

I am at my wits end. Please help me figure out how to get the tests from the `client/src` folder 
to compile in memory and execute against the pre-compiled code in `_build/js`.

Comment: I just want to second this problem because I am seeing the exact same issue using a very similar setup (I am using babel, jasmine and phantomjs, instead)

Answer (score 1):

It wont let me comment unfortunately and I realise this is not the exact answer you are looking for, but it may help you so here goes.

Have you considered using JSPM to simplify this, it can handle all of your libraries and dependancies and in conjunction with karma-jspm you won't need to declare all those paths. Some helpful links:

- https://github.com/Workiva/karma-jspm
- http://jspm.io/

Comment: yes, thank you, i have been investigating jspm for many months now. My 2 biggest problems with jspm is that it does not handle *.less transpilation, even though it does handle es6 transpilation, and it doesnot have a solid production workflow...

Comment: what i man by a production workflow is that during development you will want to load your un minified files into the browser loose leaf from where they  sit, but for production, at least for angular, you will want to preprocess the js files with ngannotate the. minify the files prior to bundling, also you will want to use the pre-bundled vendor libs, if available, or swith the config to use the CDN versions.  Furthermore, you may want ot use separate bundles for main app and vendor libs, but this is not possible with the sfx.